# How to mock a returned function from custom hook using Jest and React Testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-context

I'm facing problem while testing a component that uses custom hook. I have written a custom hook for "Spinner" that internally uses a context to provide the spinner state to the components.

Then, I used `useSpinner()` inside, say for eg, Login form component. I'm getting the below mentioned error. Also the test run didn't fail here.

`uncaught TypeError setLoading is not a function`.

`Login.tsx`

```js
...

const [loading, setLoading] = useSpinner();

  const clearForm = useCallback(() => {
    setEmail('');
    setPassword('');
    setLoading(false); /* Getting error here */
  }, [setLoading]);

  useEffect(() => () => clearForm(), [clearForm]);
...
```

`use-spinner.tsx`

```js
export default function useSpinner(): SpinnerContextType {
  const context = useContext(SpinnerContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useSpinner is used outside of SpinnerContext scope');
  }
  return context;
}
```

In my `types.ts` file, I have defined the type `SpinnerContextType`

```js
export type SpinnerContextType = [
  loading: boolean,
  setLoading: (value: boolean) => void
];
```

and `SpinnerContext.tsx` file contains

```js
const SpinnerContext = createContext<SpinnerContextType>([false, null]);
```

In my test file `Login.test.tsx`, I have created a mock for this. But it didn't work.

```js
const setLoadingMock = jest.fn((v: boolean) => {});
  jest.mock('../../hooks/use-spinner', () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    default: [false, setLoadingMock],
  }));

test('Test login', () => {
    render(
        <SpinnerContext.Provider value={[false, setLoadingMock]}>
            <Login />
        </SpinnerContext.Provider>
    );
});
```